# How can I fix MIME type errors when uploading my website to 000Webhost?

Tags: javascript, html, sass, mime-types

Can someone help me to fix some bugs?
I have a free hosting by 000Webhosting. But at the last update it goes wrong.
[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dcQ8.png)

Everything works perfectly on my local host. Everything looks good, if I want to upload it to the 000Webhost. Is there suddenly a lot wrong. The error says something about the MIME type. But I have no idea how to find or fix this. Is there anyone who can help?

I've tried googling, but it doesn't work. I have already tried to omit some files to see if it is the file, but unfortunately the same problem?.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.